# Read data from old hard drive Seagate ST-1239A

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery, partition-recovery

I received an old hard drive from which I need to read the data.
I connect it using an AT-Interface to USB connector. (I tried two different ones with the same results). I guess it is about 210-211 MB and from the early nineties.

It is recognized as a hard drive.
Windows 8.1 suggests that I "initialize" it, but I guess then all data would be lost.
In Ubuntu it shows up as /dev/sdd but without partitions.
In `hardinfo` I can see a storage device called "94354-230"

If I do `sudo parted --list` it lists the other disks in the computer and then

```
Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognized disk label
```

If I try `sudo gpart sdd` the result is:

```
**** Fatal error: cannot get sector size on dev(sdd).
```

**How can I read the data from this disk? What software or hardware or command line do I need to do it?**

More text from the hard drive case is:

```
Seagate
Model ST-1239A

SWIFT
Model 94354-230

920007-004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I could read the disk in an old computer from 2006 with an `ASUS P5N-E` motherboard and running `Windows XP`. I connected it internally and it was recognized by the BIOS and Windows. I also set the BIOS to use the slowest/oldest way of communicating with the disk.

Comment: Mark this as an answer!